# Swift Realm filter List property using an Array

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I have this property in my Realm Object

```
 var tags = List<Tag>()
 "tags": [
        {
            "tagId": "80069",
            "tagName": "A"
        },
        {
            "tagId": "80070",
            "tagName": "B"
        },
        {
            "tagId": "80071",
            "tagName": "C"
        },
        {
            "tagId": "80073",
            "tagName": "D"
        }
    ]
```

I have a view controller that can filter out the tag.

So i have several buttons to toggle the filter. What I have done is i create an array for the filter for each of my button

```
var filteredList = [String]()
```

So, if i click Button A, it will append "A" to the filteredList array, and if I click Button B, it will append "B" to the filteredList array and so on

Currently this is my filter predicate

```
let realmFilteredList = self.realm.objects(MyDTO.self).filter("ANY tags.tagName IN %@", self.filteredList)
```

However, above predicate gives me wrong result, because if let's say i want to filter the tag with property "A,B,C,D" (exact ABCD), it will return me other tag that contain either A,B,C,or D.

How can I get the tag with exact "A,B,C,D" in my search predicate?

Any help given is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to filter the results of the tags list inside your `MyDTO` object?

Comment: Is your tags order relevant? I mean ABCD its the same as BCDA?

Comment: Well Realm have a lot of limitations using Predicates, but you can make it works using a workaround if you are interested let me know I have a working solution done for this

Comment: @ReinierMelian Hi, the order is not a problem. as long as self.filteredLitst = ['A','B','C','D'] will return realm result that also consist exact ['B','A','C','D'] is also acceptable :) . As long as the 4 filtered tag are same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't achieve your goals using predicate with Realm because Realm have a lot of limitations using `Predicates` and the missing ability to handle computed properties but you can use this way as a workarround

```
    let filterList = ["A","B"]
    let realmList = realmInstance?.objects(MyDTO.self)
    let filteredArray = Array(realmList!).filter({Array($0.tags).map({$0.tagName}).sorted().joined().contains(filterList.sorted().joined())})
```

here `Array($0.tags).map({$0.tagName}).sorted().joined()` we get the tags array and convert it with map to an array of Strings then we sort that array of Strings (this will ensure that only matters the TAGS in the array not the order) and after that we convert that sorted array in a String by example your array of tags.tagName is ["B","A","C"] and after this you will get "ABC" as STRING

after that we check if that STRING contains your filterList.sorted().joined() the same procedure that was explained before

so if your filterList have ["B","C","A"] you will get "ABC"

and the we check if "ABC" contains "ABC" if so then is included in final result

Comment: Sir, thank you so much, It really working! This is what i am looking for. You are a life saver! Btw Sir, could you please elaborate what have you done there? Because i want to learn what is going on there :)

Comment: OK, I will add further explanation on this @Alvin

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! I highly appreciated what you have done!

Comment: What if I need Results type?

Comment: It's use so much CPU on large data

Comment: @sadeghbitarafan you are right, but this is a workaround, if you find a better solution please post response