# Realm: %@ IN Array of Strings

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to filter by whether a primitive array contains a string something like:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN assignedTo", meId)
self.allMyJobsObj = realm.objects(Job.self).filter(predicate)
```

But this causes a non descriptive app delegate crash.
Job looks like:

```
class Job: Object, Mappable {
    ...
    var assignedTo: List<String> = List<String>()
    ...
}
```

How can I do this query? Many Thanks!

Comment: Crash? What's the error message ?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294362/swift-realm-filter-list-property-using-an-array/49296934#49296934

Comment: Thanks @ReinierMelian I was able to figure it out from that link, I'll post an answer in a sec

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Reinier for the link,

```
let realmList = realm.objects(Job.self)
let filteredArray = Array(realmList).filter({Array($0.assignedTo).map({$0}).contains(meId)})
```

Seems to work!

Comment: But you're copying all objects then doing the filter.