# Filter a realm results list with a Swift Set or array

Tags: ios, swift, set, realm

I am trying to figure out how to delete a local stored set of Entities which are excluded from what I receive from a server api. In this case we have let's say 10 entities stored locally in realm, and the server sends me 8 entities. 6 of them corresponds to entities I already have locally, 2 are new. Locally I have 4 entities which are "outdated" because the server doesn't provide them.

Of course I could delete everything and save the new entities, but I was trying to make things more efficient.

However I don't understand, once I created a swift Set which represents the difference between the local and remote situation, how can I delete the local objects, because realm tells me i can only delete objects which belong to the realm.

I've tried working with resultset, but I can't figure out a way to filter object with a "IN" clause to which is provided a set of objects, even if I recall doing something similar in the past.

```
let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write{

let oldEvents = Array(self.events!)

var newEvents = [Event]()

for event in events{
    if let e = Mapper<Event>().map(JSONObject: event){
                        newEvents.append(e)
    }

}
//here I create a set which contains the difference between remote and local entitites, and create an Array with them
let difference = Array(Set(newEvents).subtracting(Set(oldEvents)))

//this is obviously wrong
let objToDelete = realm.objects(Event.self).filter("event in %@", difference)
realm.delete(objToDelete)

//realm.delete(difference)->this gives the error that you can delete only objects that belong to the realm

//here I would like to create or update the new events
for newEvent in newEvents{
    realm.create(Event.self, value: event, update: true)
}

}
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated on how to deal with this situation. Thanks!

Comment: You object "Event" had a primary key?

Comment: yes, "id" is the primary key

Comment: I do not think that is efficient, but you can use difference with for loop to delete the object that you need by primary key.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294362/swift-realm-filter-list-property-using-an-array/49296934#49296934