# Query List of Strings in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I am working with Realm Swift and I am running into an issue where I need to write a query that filters Realm objects by both a boolean property and a List on a Realm object.

The Realm objects I would like to filter have a List value and it contains an array of strings. The values in this List will only ever be one of the following possibilities: "US", "CA", or "US" and "CA".

How might I go about writing an appropriate predicate to filter by both a boolean and one of the values contained in the List property? So far I have tried this type of query with no success:

```
category.templates.filter("testMode = false AND countries CONTAINS 'US')
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**:
After doing some more digging around I found that this solution actually solved what I was attempting to do with Realm: [Swift Realm filter List property using an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294362/swift-realm-filter-list-property-using-an-array)